# Is there a law of total conditional mutual information?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

I came across a book where the author uses the following property of mutual information:

Let $X$,$Y$,$Z$ be arbitrary discrete random variables and let $W$ be an indicator random variable.

$$
(1)\ \ I[ X : Y \mid Z ] 
  = Pr(W=0) I[ X : Y \mid Z, W=0 ] 
  + Pr(W=1) I[ X : Y \mid Z, W=1 ]\ 
$$

I don't understand why this property holds in general. 
To show this I was thinking to proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
I[ X : Y \mid Z ] 
  &= E_z[ I[ X : Y \mid Z = z ]] \\
  &= E_w[ E_z[ I[ X: Y \mid Z = z]\ |\ W=w ] ] \\
  &= Pr(W=0)E_z[ I[ X: Y \mid Z = z]\ |\ W=0 ] \\
  &+ Pr(W=1)E_z[ I[ X: Y \mid Z = z]\ |\ W=1 ].
\end{align}
where the second line follows by the law of total expectation. 
However, this does not seem to be the right approach since it's not clear to me that 
$$
E_z[ I[ X: Y \mid Z = z]\ |\ W=w ] = I[ X : Y \mid Z, W=w ]$$
holds.

What is the right way to show (1) or is the statement incorrect in general?

Comment: The equation $(1)$ is wrong - for instance, take $Z = 0$ deterministically, so that conditioning on it can be ignored. Then the equation reads, for binary $W$, that $I(X;Y) = I(X;Y|W)$, which is of course wrong - for instance, the standard example of  $X,Y$ independent Bernoulli and $W = X \oplus Y$ violates this. Are you sure there aren't more constraints on $(X,Y,Z,W)?$ Maybe if you include a reference to the book and the place in it you saw the equation someone can take a closer look?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/120782/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3547730/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/449771/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).